# how to do automated browser testing with Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there any headless browser for dart? Or a wrapper for something like selenium? My goal is to use the browser for automated end-user testing for a website i wrote years ago. Now i need to make few changes on the site. Since it contains specific business logic, i would like to write some quick tests for the site without refactoring or modifying it for unit-tests, before i make those changes.  
It seems like a fun introduction to get more familiar with dart ecosystem as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`content-shell` is a headless browser with Dart support like Dartium
(https://www.dartlang.org/install/mac)

and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdriver can be used for Selenium test.

There is headless support for Chromium work-in-progress. When Dartium is upgraded to use this Chromium version, Dartium should be able to be run headless.

The Dart team is working on incremental JS compilation (DDC - Dart development compiler) which should allow to use Chrome as development browser. The headless mode (when available) can be used directly.

Comment: A hint what the downvote is for would be appreciated.

Comment: I would like to hear about the downvote as well.
However, i have a question about this approach.
Do i understand correctly that in order to use webdriver tests, i still have to manipulate the index.html to include dart tests as described over here (https://gist.github.com/damondouglas/5972747) or is there a way to run the tests without modifying the markup?

Comment: These are no webdriver tests. For webdriver you don't need to modify the app, just load it.

Comment: Ok, seems like it could be the right solution for my problem.
Although i bumped into some problems, a hint to right direction is appreciated.
createDriver(uri: Uri.parse("[https://www.google.com](https://www.google.com/)")).then((driver) => print("driver $driver"));
Creating driver gives me 404: Not Found. And documentation is a bit too terse on how to actually use it :/

Comment: `createDriver` needs to be the Uri to the driver, not the page you want to test. I found a basic example here https://github.com/google/webdriver.dart/issues/54

Comment: Oh, i see. At the beginning i thought that webdriver itself is going to load the page.
In case anyone else having the same misunderstanding, there's a [separate](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) executable driver that's actually driving the page. After running it, i could set the driver url like this: [http://localhost:9515](http://localhost:9515).

Comment: No, at first you need to load the driver, then you can use the `get()` command to load a page.

Comment: You might want to reword your question to something like "how to do automated browser testing with Dart", then it won't look like a question for a library or tool, which are discouraged on SO. This is what the close votes are for and probably the downvote on my answer.

Comment: Yeah, sry, forgot to mention it. But my point was that in order to use dart's webdriver i had to run a separate executable driver (in localhost or in a server) that dart's webdriver can communicate to. At the beginning i thought it is all in one package.  
Thanks for your help, Günter!

Answer (score 18):

You can use Chrome or Dartium and drive it with [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and the [webdriver package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdriver)

Here is a quick example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:webdriver/io.dart';

main() async {
  // Start the ChromeDriver process
  Process chromeDriverProcess = await Process
      .start('chromedriver', ['--port=4444', '--url-base=wd/hub']);

  await for (String browserOut in const LineSplitter()
      .bind(UTF8.decoder.bind(chromeDriverProcess.stdout))) {
    if (browserOut.contains('Starting ChromeDriver')) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Connect to it with the webdriver package
  WebDriver driver = await createDriver(
      uri: Uri.parse('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/'),
      desired: Capabilities.chrome);

  // Go to your page
  await driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com');

  //TODO: write your tests
  print(await driver.execute('return navigator.userAgent', []));

  // Take a simple screenshot
  String screenshot = await driver.captureScreenshotAsBase64();
  new File('stackoverflow.png').writeAsBytesSync(BASE64.decode(screenshot));

  driver.quit();
  chromeDriverProcess.kill();
}
```

It is not totally "headless" but it is easy to make it work on server like Travis-CI with this config:

```
before_install:
 - export DISPLAY=:99.0
 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case and requirements, you might also be able to use [`puppeteer`](https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer)

For example (from the docs), you can take a screenshot of the page

```
void main() async {
  // Start the browser and go to a web page
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  var page = await browser.newPage();

  // Setup the dimensions and user-agent of a particular phone
  await page.emulate(puppeteer.devices.pixel2XL);

  await page.goto('https://dart.dev', wait: Until.networkIdle);

  // Take a screenshot of the page
  var screenshot = await page.screenshot();

  // Save it to a file
  await File('example/_github.png').writeAsBytes(screenshot);

  await browser.close();
}
```

You can also generate a PDF, take a screenshot of a node, interact with the page, evaluate JavaScript, and use the results from your Dart code, and more.