# Selenium-like feature in flutter

Tags: python, selenium, dart, flutter, web-crawler

I have to get authenticated data from specific webpage by login. But, I didn't find that kind of feature which is supported by Python as Selenium.

How can I crawl authenticated data by crawling? I cannnot authenticate my identification by simple POST method. It always fail.

Is there any replacement method for Selenium in flutter?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdriver allows to make use of Selenium but I'm not sure this is what you actually want.

Comment: I saw the reference, but I cannot understand how to use this library. Is there an any example of crawling by webdriver?

Comment: @HaramBae https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225844/2435126 is an example

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_driver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/flutter_driver-library.html) is Flutter's version of Selenium WebDriver. Currently, Flutter recommends developers to [migrate](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests/migration) to integration_test to run integration tests. Here's a [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) on how you can get started with integration_test.